# preventing multiple clicks on a checked radiobox

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a form in which the user can give a rating from 1 to 5, this is done through radio boxes. But without check the user can click on the same button multiple times how do I prevent this?
 the code is simply written

```
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='risk' />
            <td>1<input type='radio' name='question[]' id=1 value=1 onclick='calculate_score(".$number.",this.value)'/></td>
            <td>2<input type='radio' name='question[]' id=2 value=2 onclick='calculate_score(".$number.",this.value)'/></td>
            <td>3<input type='radio' name='question[]' id=3 value=3 onclick='calculate_score(".$number.",this.value)'/></td>
            <td>4<input type='radio' name='question[]' id=4 value=4 onclick='calculate_score(".$number.",this.value)'/></td>
            <td>5<input type='radio' name='question[]' id=5 value=5 onclick='calculate_score(".$number.",this.value)'/></td>
            </table></form>";
```

could anyone tell me how to handle this?
note that the code above is only a snip it from the code and it does actually work. it's purely functional. As you can see once this radio box is clicked it goes to a javascript function do I build the check there and how would I go about something like that?

Comment: do you persist the user record?

Comment: Can you show us the code for the calculate_score() function. And yes it would be useful to include the check within the same function, or surely just recalculate the score depending on their choice? Otherwise you'll have to lock it down so they can't rechoose an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the `calculate_score()` function so that it calculates according to the status of user selections, not according to the action of checking or unchecking a button. It would be bad usability and bad functionality to prevent the user from changing his selection (except perhaps in a special game or test).

Comment: I changed the onclick event to onchange like you suggested and it works great thank you and everyone else who answered

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the button that was just checked, enabling all others, once the user changes its value , previous ones will be enabled and the new one will be disabled preventing further clicks by user to that

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a good framework (like jQuery) and put your javascript logic into a `<script>` tag, but if you did this way, you must have your reasons. To disable the clicked input element try the following snippet:

```
// i am assuming (\") will escape the quote (") character to echo
onclick='calculate_score(".$number.",this.value); this.onclick=\"\";'
```